# What does「ごとが」mean?

Tags: particle-が, parsing

Is this (the phrase/word ごとが) a grammar point or vocabulary? I tried to look it up in Takoboto dictionary but it doesn't return a specific word.

Also, if the phrase/word 「ごとが」 is a grammar point. How do I use it?

The context, where I found the word, lies in the song 翼をください ([an ending song version of Nichijou](http://nichijou.wikia.com/wiki/Tsubasa_wo_Kudasai#Japanese))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the ごとが  in

> いま私の願いごとがかなうならば翼がほしい

If this is the case, then you're parsing the sentence incorrectly. The ごと forms part of a noun phrase with 願い. You can find it on [Takeboto under お願い事](http://takoboto.jp/?w=1949390). Here's the underlying structure (I've used bold to highlight the different grammatical components):

> **願いごと** が **かなう**

The が is your standard subject marker. Thus, the subject of the sentence is 願いごと and the main verb is かなう, which means for a 願い to be come true/be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are referring to this part of the lyrics:

> いま わたしの願い**ごとが**
>   叶うならば 翼が欲しい
>   この 背中に鳥のように
>   白い翼 つけてください

In which case you are parsing it incorrectly.  It actually breaks down like this

> いま　わたしの　願いごと　が

Where 願いごと means "desire" or "thing wished for".  In conjunction with the next line, it's saying "If my wish were fulfilled now..."